# How to merging 2pdf's with pdftk where output file have name one of them

Tags: windows, batch, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have many pair's of PDF's to merging with different names. I need to merging pair, without the first page of the second PDF and call the output file the name of the second PDF. First pdf name's always beginning with "MX-" . Sorry for my english.
For example
pdftk A=**MX**-2021.09.29.pdf B=**apple**.pdf cat A1 B2-end output **apple**.pdf
or
pdftk A=**MX**-2021.08.21.pdf B=**orange**.pdf cat A1 B2-end output **orange**.pdf

Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: How are the pdfs stored are they all in one folder or the pairs separated by folder? If they are all in 1 big folder how do you know which pairs should belong together

Comment: The output PDF filename can’t be set to the name of an input filename.

Comment: I put one pair to the certain folder.

Comment: it is allowed to save output file to another folder